# How to get camera settings from video file shot with Nikon D3300 DSLR?

Tags: dslr, nikon

I have videos shot with Nikon D3300 like DSC_0027.MOV. I tried using ffprobe program but it does not give camera settings. I am looking for settings like focal length, fstops, what mode the camera was like Manual, S or Landscape etc. in which the video was shot. How can I get such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all the available metadata using a free Exif Tool which you can read about [here](https://www.scantips.com/lights/exif.html). You need to bear in mind that you're less likely to extract as much Exif data from video as you are with photo.

This is due to things like ISO, shutter and aperture changing all the time during the recording of video, and therefore is not logged to a specific value/setting like it is with photo. However, you're likely to find just about all you're able to using this tool (and many of the others just like it).

A highly recommended tool known for extracting more data than others is [Exif Tool by Phil Harvey](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)